# Solving $x^2+x+1=7^n$

Tags: prime-numbers, cyclotomic-polynomials, perfect-powers

Do simple equations $x^2+x+1=7^n$ have infinitely or finitely many solutions? In fact, what about the general equation $x^2+x+1=p^n$ where $p$ is a prime congruent to $1$ $\pmod 3$?

Are there any more solutions $(x,n)$ to $x^2+x+1=7^n$ besides $(2,1)$ and $(18,3)$? I would expect no but I am not sure?

I know the case $x^2+1=5^n$ has finitely many solutions $(x,n)$ (and $(2,1)$ is the only solution) due to Catalan's theorem on consecutive perfect powers.

Comment: To list the obvious: Because $x^2-xy+y^2$ is the norm of the algebraic integer $x+\omega y$, $\omega=(-1+i\sqrt3)/2$, we know from elementary algebraic number theory that every prime $p\equiv 1\pmod3$ can be written in the form $x^2-xy+y^2=p$. Consequently the same holds for $p^n$. The set of Eisensteinian integers with norm $7^n$ can be described explicitly as $\pm(2\pm i\sqrt3)^n\omega^j, j=0,1,2,$ and the task is to check whether that recipe spits out more $(x,y)$ pairs such that one of them is $=-1$.